# ransack gem rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ransack

i am getting stuck with using the gem ransack. I have placed ransack in my gemfile and then run bundle install ( though i used just bundle, does that make a difference? i didnt think it did?)

Next i have placed this in my Recipe controller

```
 def all_recipes
 @q = Recipe.search(params[:q])
 @searchresults = @q.result(:distinct => true)
 end
```

Within my view (all_recipes)i have the search form and block to display my results

```
      <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :dish_name_cont %>
      <%= f.text_field :dish_name_cont %>
      <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
      ---------------------

      <% @searchresults.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= r.dish_name %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
```

Ive got two problems, without even conducting a search i get this in my view where the block is

```
fish and chips my first recipe lasagne Lasagne
```

and then if i search say las it redirects me to my index page after the get request but as i have no block to display the results i get an undefined error, which is expected.

After this i placed my controller code within the index action and the form and block within the index view and now it all works? Why cant i use the all_recipes action and why does it redirect?

Answer (score 0):

In depth demo, may be helpful - http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast

Comment: watched this railscast episode, doesn't explain why i can only place in index action, unless im missing something?